# OAuth in .net or mono.mac

Tags: .net, mono, oauth-2.0, restful-authentication

im trying to use an api rest from ShareFile and i need to authenticate and get a token for doing that, in the share file page there is some information how to do it, but is not clear, this is my first time with OAuth someone knows a little example o blog with the samples for guiding me. 
it would be very appreciated 
thanks in advance

Comment: If the documentation is not clear, you should contact the vendor support directly or refer to existing sample code, such as https://code.google.com/p/sharefile-api-php/